# How do I update my IOS App with PhoneGap 2.7 to 3.4 when I use an old plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

How do I update my IOS App with PhoneGap 2.7 to 3.4 when I use an old plugin.

My problem is that I use a PhoneGap plugin "ios-Tabbar plugin" which unfortunately has not been updated for PhoneGap 3 *.

Is it possible to update PhoneGap manual in Xcode, by replacing the packages and classes that belong to PhoneGap, just as you could in the old PhoneGap versions prior to 3.0.

Jacob

Answer (score 1):

Main changes

1. config.xml structure changed

in **2.7**

```
<plugin name="Echo" value="Echo" onload="true" />
```

in **3.4**

```
<feature name="Echo">
    <param name="ios-package" value="Echo" />
</feature>
```

and you can use older native code because no changes in the native side  check plugin dev docs **[3.4](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins)** and **[2.7](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)** i think this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was just the answer I wanted.

And then replace PhoneGap 2.7 code with new 3.4, just as they did in the past before Phonegap 3.0

Hope you can understand my bad english, come from Denmark.

Jacob